# AWS S3 Presigned URL upload image with postman

Tags: amazon-s3, postman

I need to upload a file to S3 with postman for testing. I have a generated presigned URL from S3.

But I don't know how to configure postman correctly for doing this PUT request to my generated presigned URL.

The response on postman with malformed headers is:

> > > ```
> > > <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
> > > <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
> > > ```

the params for the presigned request:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: 'ss-files-dev',
  Key: 'dansero.jpg',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  Expires: 100
};
```

I get the URL, then enter it in postman, with PUT request, but the headers are not complete?
1. if I add content-type on header, there is no response from server
2. in body for the request Im attaching file as "binary"

[image: postmanConfig]

How to do my PUT request from postman?, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure about the following things:

1-The file name equal and same as the key when you get the signed URL.

2-Get the signed URL for putObject by passing the right parameter to getSignedUrl.

For put request not needs to set any additional headers.

Comment: hi @reza,  I unticked all the headers values,  and the name is equal in file and request for signed url, what else can it be? thanks!

Comment: Please check this question and answer; I have the same advice for both case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51414212/upload-file-to-s3-via-curl-using-presigned-url/51415060?noredirect=1#comment89801418_51415060

Answer (score 10):

For me, Postman added hidden headers. If I remove the Content-Type header, the Put worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working in Postman using a POST request with “form-data” input. I put all the details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479206/call-s3-pre-signed-url-with-postman/60742599#60742599) stack overflow post.