# Ppload file to S3 via cURL using presigned URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I'm getting a pre-signed URL to upload a file on S3 bucket.

this is the curl command:

```sh
curl -v -T ./dansero.jpg 'https://ss-files-dev.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dansero.jpg\?AWSAccessKeyId\=AKIAIT6VM43PPNS43Y7Q\&Expires\=1531973770\&Signature\=hNvG5rnICkk58mMBLeMgHGDZ93c%3D'
```

That gives me the error:

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Here my node.js generation of the presigned URL

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({

  accessKeyId: 'aaa',
  secretAccessKey: 'bbb+oeyjn8zGANuDyCIY',
  region: 'ap-southeast-2'
});

const params = {
  Bucket: 'ss-files-dev',
  Key: 'dansero.jpg'  
};

});

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, urlsign) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log(urlsign);
});
```

So where is my problem in the URL generation or the curl?
thanks

Comment: Remove all the the backslashes \ from your URL.  You are providing the URL to curl using a `'` single-quoted string, so these are not needed and in fact don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the sign request part. Make sure get signed URL for put object.
It is working code from my script:

```
 s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, urlsign) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var output = {
                url: urlsign
            };
            cb(null, output);
        });
```

Try put the object into your bucket by simple put request like this:

```
                        var req = http.request({
                            hostname: 's3.amazonaws.com',
                            port: 80,
                            path:{YOURPRESIGNEDURL}.replace('https://s3.amazonaws.com', ''),
                            method: 'PUT',
                        }, function(res) {
```

Finally, make sure about the following things:

1-User policy and right IAM for your key. You should have the permission to put objects like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14546345345",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2- I think you should pass -X PUT in your curl request.

Comment: hi @reza, thanks for the reply, i updated my code, I had the sign request, now on answer, same problem, thanks