# AWS S3, File Upload from Angular or JS or Python or whatever

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-post, boto3, pre-signed-url

So I have been attempting to do what I thought would be a simple task. To gain some practice with AWS and a front end framework I wanted to build a webpage where a user could click on an upload button and that would send the file to an S3 bucket where I could interact with it with lambda functions. I have experience with HTML, JavaScript, python, and can find my way around angular, I have also spun up my own flask web servers so I am familiar with the ideas of requests, APIs and REST. Python is the language I am strongest in at the moment.

However now that I have started trying to apply this to AWS I run into allot of issues.

1. Is there a really simple way of uploading a file (image) to an S3 bucket I am just missing? This seems like it should be easier.
2. The best practice approach I have found but not gotten to work is that you should generate a presigned URL / post request and then use that from the client side to conduct the upload. However examples such as [Official boto3 example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html), [Using an S3 presigned POST](https://gist.github.com/alexdebrie/3e8b96217f5aff01227050b17a24e380), and [AWS S3 uploads using presigned URLs](https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d). Have not seemed to work for me, usually failing in a HTTP 400, bad request response. I have tried making the request from [python](http://%7B%27url%27:%20%27https://the--abyss.s3.amazonaws.com/%27,%20%27fields%27:%20%7B%27key%27:%20%27upload.jpg%27,%20%27AWSAccessKeyId%27:%20%27AKIAVBYPN3PB35LZFIEE%27,%20%27policy%27:%20%27eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjAtMTAtMjlUMDA6Mjc6MDdaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJidWNrZXQiOiAidGhlLS1hYnlzcyJ9LCB7ImtleSI6ICJ1cGxvYWQuanBnIn1dfQ==%27,%20%27signature%27:%20%27Ol+4+tMXSR6IsCOZK5sB+sblq+U=%27%7D%7D) requests (response: 400), [curl](http://curl%20-v%20-F%20key=upload.jpg%20-F%20AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVBYPN3PB35LZFIEE%20-F%20policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjAtMTAtMjhUMTc6MjU6MzVaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJidWNrZXQiOiAidGhlLS1hYnlzcyJ9LCB7ImtleSI6ICJ1cGxvYWQuanBnIn1dfQ==%20-F%20signature=mhJmsua7uVCJRi7DYzdkbquEGSY=%20-F%20file=@upload.jpg%20http://the--abyss.s3.amazonaws.com) (response: 400), and [postman](https://the--abyss.s3.amazonaws.com/?Content-Type=jpg&key=upload.jpg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVBYPN3PB35LZFIEE&policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjAtMTAtMjhUMTk6MTg6MDBaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJhY2wiOiAicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSwgeyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiAicG5nIn0sIHsiYnVja2V0IjogInRoZS0tYWJ5c3MifSwgeyJrZXkiOiAidXBsb2FkLmpwZyJ9XX0=&signature=pEVW3dq6KOjUs2kRkjJ4ceR4J7U=) (response: AccessDenied). [dictionary, command, and request are in the links, I will upload code once I know I have a viable approach]
3. When I was looking into things I found [POST Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html), this seems to detail the fields for a post request under the V4 framework for AWS. They appear to be different than the fields returned by the methods in the examples above for generating a presigned request. [Call S3 presigned URL with postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479206/call-s3-pre-signed-url-with-postman/60742599#60742599) seems to detail a recent working request consistent with the V4 schema yet the [Signature Version 4 signing process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) don't use boto3 or the aws-sdk which seems like the wrong way to head.

Therefore my questions as a noob are am I going down the right approach and if so what would the debugging strategy be as I have many possible points of failure from malformed requests to a bad CORS on the S3 bucket or a badly configured IAM. I don't know where to begin.

If someone tells me I am not barking up the wrong tree, Ill put up a code example. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So as you said you are sending an user uploaded object from your web-page (Web-server) to S3. Where is your Web-server running? Does it have proper configurations to access S3. Also the reasons postman might get access denied is because your bucket might not be public or it has some bucket policy. Need some more details here.

Comment: So i think i have gotten most of this working, it was two types of security issue. My Block public access setting was on for the bucket. As well the example code above attempts to generate a signature for a prior version of AWS auth, you need to use signature_version='s3v4',  AKA,  AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Comment: That said i am now a little worried about how i have configured the bucket? The whole Block public access thing is hard to understand. I do have CORS and APM setup, and basic tests seem to show the bucket is not actually public, but us there something else i should do for security?